# Symfony3 validate field only when adding object

Tags: php, validation, annotations, entity, symfony

I have got some problem.
In the enitity I have set validation.
I have there term field, which is required (NotBlank constraint).
It works fine, but when someone is editing the object I want to disable the validation on this field; then it's not required, because someone already uploaded this file. Of course I have only one form, one view and two actions in controller.
How can I deal with such situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) for this.

Since validation takes place before flushing, your entity won't have an `id`, add a constraint that looks like this:

```
class YourEntity
{
    // ...
    private $term;

    /**
    * @Assert\Callback
    */
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (!$this->getId() && !$this->getTerm()) {
            $context->buildViolation('This field is required!')
                ->atPath('term')
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is ok, but firstly I want to find some solution with validation in annotations.

Comment: Ok, I have analysed this. This solution is much better for me in this concerete situation. Thanks! :)

Comment: No problem! If you want to use annotation, you can try to create a rule using `Assert\Expression()`. I'm sure it's possible, but this solution will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behaviour by validation groups: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups

The definition would be:

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"creation"})
 */
private $terms;
```

And for the validation you do:

```
$errors = $validator->validate($someVar, null, array('creation'));
```

when creating and

```
$errors = $validator->validate($someVar, null, array('edit'));
```

when editing.

Comment: I read about groups, but I just want to change the validation only for this one field and only when editing. In this solution I have to make 2 groups. Is there any other solution, to make it work in another way? BTW, Where should I put this: $errors = $validator->validate($author, null, array('registration')); ?